# Different ways of using locators to access the rows in a table?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am trying to learn proper use of locators to find nested elements. Using a modified table from w3school (for illustration porpouses), what is a good way of collecting the row elements belonging to the tbody (while exclude those belonging to thead)?

I was thinking:

```
element(by.tagName('tbody')).element.all(by.tagName('tr'))
```

This does not work since a sublocator can not be a an elementArrayFinder (if I have understood correctly).

Is it possible to write:

```
element.all(by.css('tbody tr')) ?
```

(I will try that last tomorrow after a long day).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nested selection in Protrator, you have to all diretly to the previous all method call like,

```
element(by.tagName('tbody')).all(by.tagName('tr'))
```

Even you can use to select the deep child like this,

```
element(by.tagName('tbody')).all(by.tagName('td'))
```

Yes. `by.css('tbody tr')` is for finding element by css selector. Using them in element.all() will return all the element matching the css selector.

```
 element.all(by.css('tbody tr'));
```

As it is tr a immediated child, you can try this as well,

```
element.all(by.css('tbody>tr'));
```